# mvn pax:provision (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Fragment bundles can not be started.)

Tags: java, maven, osgi, pax

Here are some parts of my parent pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

     .
     .
     .

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.ops4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-pax-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
</plugin>
```

If I run `mvn pax:provision` everything works fine except one thing. I get:

> `Auto-properties start: file:bundles/slf4j.jdk14_1.6.1.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Fragment bundles can not be started.)`

The message is clear but how can I tell the pax plugin that slf4j.jdk is a fragment and not a bundle?

Although I get the error all Bundles are Active respectively the fragment is resolved. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm aware of is using an explicit `<provision>` element with a `@nostart` suffix. These arguments are passed verbatim to [Pax Runner](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxrunner/Provisioning).